# fstab being ignored in osx ventura; possible to use it in Ventura MacOS?

Tags: macos, fstab, macos-ventura

I have an OSX running Ventura 13.4.1. I've created an fstab file (in /etc) that contains an entry for mounting a linux server running smb. The entry is correct, and mounts properly when processed with a command line 'mount , so I know the fstab file is properly set up.

However, the mount is not performed (appearing to ignore the fstab file) when the machine is restarted. While fstab is not present by default in /etc on this mac, I suspect that the process that uses fstab is not running.

My current basic fstab entry is:

//myservername/Sharepath /Volumes/Shares/MyMountPoint smbfs rw,auto,nobrowse 0 2

The Shares/MyMountPoint folder has already been created in Volumes, with wide open permissions for testing.

The goal here in using fstab is to mount my smb-based linux server shares on the Macs and have those mounts accessible *before* any users log into the machines. Backups are performed via SSH and before logins and must have local access to those shares.

Is fstab deactivated now and can it still be used?

Comment: Please include your `/etc/fstab` in the question.

Comment: @Gilby, per your suggestion I've added the fstab entry and more detail about goals.

Comment: Web research suggest to me that `fstab` is not sufficient. You may need to involve `automount` and `autofs`. The autofs links at the bottom of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/353351/clever-sysadmin-needed-how-to-keep-smb-shares-mounted may be useful.  All this is beyond my practical experience, so I hope someone else can help a bit better than me!

Comment: And this one more so https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441952/mount-nas-drive-at-a-specified-mount-point-make-it-persistent/457190#457190  Looks like @Seamus is an expert on this.

Comment: @Gilby, I checked out those posts. So far I've found nothing to indicate that fstab is being processed by default is MacOS Ventura at this time. It doesn't seem so much "insufficient" as disabled. I've tried automount and autofs, but neither seems to mount between bootup and before any user logs in. Thanks for the links.